# Query optimisation (autonumbering)

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, subquery, inner-join

I have these two tables (simplified), can contain a lot of appointment and a lot of episodes

**Appointment**

```
date       | person_id | episode_id  
-----------+-----------+------------
12-11-2019 |    1      |    1
18-10-2019 |    1      |    1
11-10-2019 |    1      |    1
10-12-2018 |    1      |    2
10-11-2018 |    1      |    2
```

**Episodes**

```
episode_id | Name
-----------+------------
    1      | Episode 1
    2      | Episode 2
```

Now I need to list the number of the appointment (in the sequence) inside an episode.

So result of the query will be:

```
Appointment | Episode    | Appointment number
------------+------------+----------------------
12-11-2019  | Episode 1  |     3
18-10-2019  | Episode 1  |     2
11-10-2019  | Episode 1  |     1
10-12-2018  | Episode 2  |     2
10-11-2018  | Episode 2  |     1
```

So my query (simplified) looks like this:

```
select 
    a.date, e.name, 
    (select count(*) from appointment a1 
     where a1.espisode_id = a.episode_id and a1.date < a.date ) + 1 
From 
    appointment a 
join 
    episode e on e.episode_id = a.episode_id 
where 
    a.person_id = 1
```

Now this works fine, but the sub select statement is killing the database. We got over 5 million appointments and over a million episodes.

Any ideas how to optimise this, so it is less database heavy?

Answer (score 3):

Use window functions!

```
select a.date, e.name, 
    row_number() over(partition by a.episode_id order by a.date) as appointment_number
from appointment a 
inner join episode e on e.episode_id = a.episode_id 
where a.person_id = 1
```